# Visual Paradigm;import from Visio 2013

Tags: uml, activity-diagram, visual-paradigm, visio2013

I use `Microsoft visio 2013` and `Visual Paradigm`.I want to import an activity diagram that is created by visio into visual paradigm.[Here, Versatile Output Formats](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/features/output-export-import/) of visual paradigm says:

> Carry on software design by importing legacy design from Visio drawing
>   (.vdx).

But there is no option in visio 2013 for exporting as `.vdx` file.Also [Introduction to the Visio 2013 file format (.vsdx)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj228622(v=office.15).aspx) says:

> Visio 2013 introduces a new file format (.vsdx) for Visio that
>   replaces the Visio binary file format (.vsd) and Visio XML Drawing
>   file format (.vdx)...
>   Developers who are familiar with the Visio XML Drawing file format
>   (.vdx) from previous versions of Visio can find many of the same XML
>   structures within the parts of .vsdx file format.

But how I can get or find `.vdx` file of a diagram in visio 2013 or is there a way to import `.vsdx` to visual paradigm?

Comment: See:http://www.file-extensions.org/convert-vsdx-to-vdx

Comment: [TechNet: Compatibility > Changes in Office 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc178954(v=office.15).aspx): "_...Visio 2013 does not support saving to the Visio 2003 XML format. This affects VDX, VSX, and VTX file formats ... Visio 2013 has a new XML based file format..._". So it's probably time to ask the tool's vendor for support of the new Visio file format or you can use a legacy Visio version to do the conversion

Answer (score 1):

According to Microsoft you can `File -> Save As` to type `Visio 2003-2010 Drawing (*.vsd)`

**Reference** [Save a Visio file as an earlier version](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/Save-a-Visio-file-as-an-earlier-version-7926e2fb-3648-4fbc-b121-9bae2341da25?CTT=1&CorrelationId=a0d1d306-1f0f-4511-b9e3-373524e8a932&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US):

> **Save a Visio file as an earlier version**
>
> You can share files with people using Visio 2003 or later by saving
>   your diagram file in the appropriate file format.
>
> - Click the File tab.
> - In the side bar, click Save As.
> - Under Choose a location, click the option you want.
> - Under Choose a folder, click Browse for Additional Folders.
> - **In the Save as type drop-down list, select Visio 2003-2010 Drawing (*.vsd).**
> - Browse to the location where you want to save the file and click Save.
>
> If your diagram uses features that are not available in earlier
>   versions of Visio, the Microsoft Visio Compatibility Checker dialog
>   appears and lists the features that cannot be saved, or that will look
>   different in the earlier format. Click Continue to save anyway, or
>   Cancel if you want to change the diagram and remove the advanced
>   features before you save it.
>
> Applies To: **Visio 2013**, Visio

You can then use a number of different utilities to convert `vsd` to `vdx`. One example online converter is at [Visio Files Conversion](http://www.conceptdraw.com/helpdesk/content/visio-conversion):

> ConceptDraw Visio File Conversion is a free web service, that is
>   available to anyone who has a requirement to open Visio (VSD)
>   documents in ConceptDraw PRO.
>
> This service was created for Mac OS users , who need to open visual
>   documents saved in Visio(VSD) file format.
>
> **The service converts files from Visio binary file format VSD into
>   Visio XML files which will then have a VDX file extension.**
>
> To use our free file conversion service you should email your .vsd
>   file. as attachment. Our automated Visio File Converter will convert
>   the file to .vdx and you will be able to view it in 15 minutes or
>   less.
>
> You can even send multiple .vsd files to us, compressed in a .zip format.
>   Our automated service will extract and convert each file, then send the converted files back to you in the same compression format in which you originally sent them.

Comment: I tried that.Visual paradigm can import converted file,but it has no flow lines and some shapes are deformed.

Comment: That is always a potential problem when using converters and/or exporting/importing to convert from one file format to another. Did you try different converters or just one?